# Yielding a process in Linux

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I want to yield a multithreaded process in Linux. I know a thread can be yielded by calling `sched_yield`. I guess, on the other hand, the whole process can be yielded by calling `sleep(0)`, since `sleep` works at process level. Am I right?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Kernel will happily interrupt your process when needed.

Answer (score 5):

sched_yield will yield the thread that is currently running, relinquishing the rest of its timeslice. The processor then context switches to the next thread. Whether that thread is another which belongs to your process is unknown. It could be, it might not be.

To yield the whole process you would therefore need to yield each thread that existed in that process. sleep works similarly. It will sleep for that particular thread, not the whole process.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong.

[sleep(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sleep.3.html)

> sleep() makes **the calling thread** sleep until seconds seconds have
> elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored.

#### EDIT

From the comments I see people use an outdated site for the manual pages. Stop using that site, use the kernel.org pages which should be up-to-date.

Comment: Well its really confusing, isn't it. Here, http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_yield, it says that sched_yield yields a process and here, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sched_yield.html, it says it reqlinquises a thread! Who to believe?

Comment: @MetallicPriest The standard is "how it should be done". The kernel.org page is "how they actually did it". And linux.die.net is just awful.

Comment: sleep() makes the current process sleep until seconds seconds have elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored. Taken from the Linux Manual, http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep! So you are wrong cnicutar!

Comment: @Daniel A. White It's outdated and filled with mistakes. Avoid it at all cost.

Comment: Guys, guys. Stop reading junk (linux.die.net). Use the real manual or the standard :-)

Comment: So cnicutar, what according to you is right for yielding the whole process? Any idea?

Comment: @MetallicPriest You might get away with yielding every thread :-/ But in practice you *rarely* need this.